# Including a PHP file then PHP foreach loop in a html table

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach, html-table

Not sure if this is the best way to do this.. But..

I've got a PHP file calling an API and doing a foreach loop to get all the data I want. Previously I was calling this from my html file and putting it into a table, the problem was that it was all appearing as technically the same row and that made formatting hard.

This is what I used to have:

```
<div class="bgimg2 w3-container">

 <table class="w3-table w3-medium w3-text-white">
<tr class="w3-blue-gray">
  <th> <h5> Name </h5> </th>
  <th> <h5> Size </h5> </th>
  <th> <h5> % </h5> </th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th> <h4> <div id=queue> </h4> </th>
  <th> <h4> <div id=queueSize> </h4> </th>
  <th> <h4> <div id=queuePercent> </h4> </th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
```

I want to have each item appearing as it's own row, so I'm trying to do a php foreach loop directly in the table.

This is what I've got currently for the table:

```
<table class="w3-table w3-medium w3-text-white">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
        require_once ('/api/sabapiQueue.php');
        foreach ($apiResultDataShift as $row){
        ?>
        <tr>
         <td> <?php $row['filename']  ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <?php  } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

It's not working and the file isn't even loading. Not sure where I've gone wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Previously I was calling this from my html file and putting it into a table` is it still a HTML file?

Comment: What's in the `sabapiQueue.php`? Does the file exists with a `.php` or `.html`? And please add `echo` here: `<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>`

Comment: Main thing jumping out at me... This is *not* an `echo` statement: `<?php $row['filename']  ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you missed a detail in not echoing out your variable.  I would also suggest, and perhaps introduce you to [alternative PHP syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) which is good for when you want to tightly integrate a few php blocks into html as you are doing here:

```
<table class="w3-table w3-medium w3-text-white">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
    require_once ('/api/sabapiQueue.php');
    foreach ($apiResultDataShift as $row):
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?= $row['filename'] ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php 
    endforeach;
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternatively, as per the [echo manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) you could just change this line:

```
<td><?php echo $row['filename']; ?></td>
```

Comment: Using : with endforeach is a good approach when combining PHP and HTML together.